# Send user level messages to syslog

Tags: linux, logging, python, syslog

I currently have syslog.conf like so to send INFO logs to /var/log/messages

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none; /var/log/messages;
```

I have an application that uses python libraries  `LOG_USER` facility to log [Python Ref doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html), but these logs are not getting sent to /var/log/messages

I would like to update my syslog.conf file to my config file (line above) to include `LOG_USER` messages. From what I can see `LOG_USER` maps to syslog user-level messages [syslog ref](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=426638) but I cannot figure out what I need to add ot my conf file.

Any direction appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
*.info;user.*;mail.none;authpriv.none; /var/log/messages;
```

I added "user.*" part, which causes syslog daemon to accept LOG_USER messages.